# Why does this code hang when running on the actual BCM2837 (pi 3) but runs fine with qemu

Tags: c++, c, assembly, raspberry-pi3, arm64

Consider the following function:

```
_atomic_raw_lock:
.global _atomic_raw_lock
.type _atomic_raw_lock, %function
1:  ldxr        x9, [x0]                //atomic load from memory pointed to by x0
    cbz         x9, 2f                  //branch if zero (unlocked)
    wfe                                 //sleep if locked
    b           1b
2:  mov         x9, #0x01               //set x9 to be LOCKED (1).
    stxr        w10, x9, [x0]
    dsb         sy
    cbz         w10, 3f                 // atomic store success?
    b           1b
3:  ret
```

The function is called from c code and stores an address to a 64 bit integer in x0 as its first parameter.  The program runs as expected in qemu.  I have determined this is the problem area by setting hardware pins right before and after this line that calls this function.  This function never returns. x9 and w10 are caller saved (I assume the c calling code will save these automatically).

details: 
running on pi 3 b+
compiling with aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu (glibc static link) cross chain from toolchains.bootlin.com **Everything runs fine on real hardware untill this function is called.**
build command:

```
aarch64-linux-g++ -g -std=gnu++17 -O0 -Wall -fno-exceptions -Wextra -Wno-attributes -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -Wno-sign-compare -c start.S -o 
aarch64-linux-ld start.o main.o -T link.ld -o kernel8.elf -l:libc.a -l:libstdc++.a -l:libc.so -l:libgcc_s.so
```

ld file:

```
OUTPUT_ARCH(aarch64)
ENTRY(_start)
    MEMORY
    {
        RAM (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x80000, LENGTH = 0x40000000
    }
SECTIONS
{
    PROVIDE(__start_prog_mem = .); /*I may want to use this in c somehow*/
    .text : /*The place where code goes*/
    { 
        KEEP(*(.text.boot)) /*Keep this even if it is not used*/
        *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t*) /*all variations of text and
        the gnu generated (for the c ability) text sections*/
    } > RAM /*These sections now belong in .text*/
    .bss : /*Uninitialized data goes here, will not load at runtime.*/
    {
        . = ALIGN(4); /*align the current location to 4 bytes*/
        __bss_start = .; /*define __bss_start to be at the current location.*/
        *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
        *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4); /*align the current location to 4 bytes*/
        __bss_end = .; /*Define __bss_end to be at the current location.*/
    } > RAM
    .data : /*Initialized global and static data*/
    {
        . = ALIGN(4); /*align the current location to 4 bytes*/
        __data_begin = .;
        *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d*) /*Put all data sections here.*/
        *(.rel.data .rel.data.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __data_end = .;
    } > RAM
    .rodata : /*const data*/
    {
        . = ALIGN(4); /*align the current location to 4 bytes*/
        __rodata_begin = .;
        *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r*) /*All const data sections, 
        including the gnu leftovers*/
        *(.rel.rodata .rel.rodata.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __rodata_end = .;
    } > RAM
    .stack_core0 :
    {
        . = ALIGN(16); /*stack must be 16 byte aligned*/
        __stack_start_core0 = .;
        . = . + 1024;  /*el0 size*/
        __el0_stack_core0 = .; /*el0 stack*/
        . = . + 1048576; /*el1 size*/
        __el1_stack_core0 = .; /*el1 stack*/
        PROVIDE(__el1_stack_core0 = .);
        . = . + 16384; /*el2 stack size*/
        __el2_stack_core0 = .;
        . = ALIGN(16);
        __stack_end_core0 = .;
    } > RAM
    .stack_core1 :
    {
        . = ALIGN(16); /*stack must be 16 byte aligned*/
        __stack_start_core1 = .;
        . = . + 1024;  /*el0 size*/
        __el0_stack_core1 = .; /*el0 stack*/
        . = . + 1048576; /*el1 size*/
        __el1_stack_core1 = .; /*el1 stack*/
        PROVIDE(__el1_stack_core1 = .);
        . = . + 16384; /*el2 stack size*/
        __el2_stack_core1 = .;
        . = ALIGN(16);
        __stack_end_core1 = .;
    } > RAM
    .stack_core2 :
    {
        . = ALIGN(16); /*stack must be 16 byte aligned*/
        __stack_start_core2 = .;
        . = . + 1024;  /*el0 size*/
        __el0_stack_core2 = .; /*el0 stack*/
        . = . + 1048576; /*el1 size*/
        __el1_stack_core2 = .; /*el1 stack*/
        PROVIDE(__el1_stack_core2 = .);
        . = . + 16384; /*el2 stack size*/
        __el2_stack_core2 = .;
        . = ALIGN(16);
        __stack_end_core2 = .;
    } > RAM
    .stack_core3 :
    {
        . = ALIGN(16); /*stack must be 16 byte aligned*/
        __stack_start_core3 = .;
        . = . + 1024;  /*el0 size*/
        __el0_stack_core3 = .; /*el0 stack*/
        . = . + 1048576; /*el1 size*/
        __el1_stack_core3 = .; /*el1 stack*/
        PROVIDE(__el1_stack_core3 = .);
        . = . + 16384; /*el2 stack size*/
        __el2_stack_core3 = .;
        . = ALIGN(16);
        __stack_end_core3 = .;
    } > RAM
    _end = .; /*Define _end to be at the current location*/
    PROVIDE(__end_prog_mem = .); /*I may want to use this in c somehow*/
    .heap :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __heap_start = .;
    } > RAM
    /DISCARD/ : /*Any sections listed here will not be included*/
    {
        /* *(.comment*) /*Exclude any comments made by the compiler*/
        /* *(.gnu*) /*Exclude any version numbers included by the compiler*/
        /* *(.note*) /*Exclude any notes made by the compiler.*/
        /* *(.eh_frame*) /*This sections is ecluded because it contains asyncronous
        unwind tbles we dont need.*/
    } 
}

__bss_size = (__bss_end - __bss_start) >> 3; /*Define the symbol to hold the 
size of the .bss sections.  This size will be in single units of 8 bytes 
(due to shift >> 3)*/
__prog_mem_size = (__end_prog_mem - __start_prog_mem);
```

Removed the atomic locking mechanism (the code list at the very top) allows the program to run, but output is jumbled due to non-thread safe code.  Even a simple bool flag will not work because of the normal read-modify-write is not multi-core safe.

Question restated: Why does this run on the emulator (qemu) but not actual hardware. _atomic_raw_lock function list above has been confirmed as hanging when called on real hardware but not on qemu.

EDIT: The code runs fine in QEMU which leads me to believe it is not a deadlock. I have confirmed this by running a test where all the program does is lock once and spin forever.  The problem persists under those circumstances.

Comment: My experience with 64 bits on RPI 3+ was, that I got unstable behavior as soon as something other than raspbian was running on it.

Comment: Tell me about it.... Maybe I will check the raspbian source and see how it does load-aquire store-release.

Comment: it's 32 bit though. I ran a 64-bit [debian](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi3) port

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for it to fail (erratically) if the provided memory is anything other than *NORMAL*.

Qemu would be unlikely to model the memory attributes and mimic such failures.

( sorry about the stxr, my mind was in cswap ).

You might consider dropping an iteration count into the loop so you can bail out to the debugger/crash dump if it is hanging in there.

Comment: w10 is the status of the store, and if it fails, the "b 1b" branches back to retry and gain the lock again.

Comment: Yes, I will do that (iteration loop). At the very least it will give me more info about what's happening.